# URL Rewrite IIS 7.5 - only for port 80

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I setup IIS to redirect non https traffic to https by using the rewrite wizzard in IIS.  I followed the steps outlined here:  https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9953/38/iis-redirect-http-to-https.

Now I'm wanting to add a condition to say if the {server_port} = 80.

I added a new condition: 
Condition Input: {Server_Port}
Check if input string: matches the pattern
pattern: 80

Under conditions : Logical Grouping: match all

I then saved the rule and restarted IIS.

I'm still getting all traffic to my site redirected to https which tosses Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG since https:// [www.mysite.com:83](http://www.mysite.com:83) does not compute.

How do I write the condition to redirect only if the server port is 80?

Please be aware that I have not written my redirect in the web.config and am asking because most of the examples I've found discuss web.config. I did find a web config example that should work, but I can't figure out how to use the rewrite tool to implement this:

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="XXXX" negate="true" />
   </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: That doesn't help. I already know that my rewrite isn't configured correctly. I'm asking for help making it correct. Using your link only shows me that it's not working properly. And it's relying on web.config. I'm trying to use the rewrite module in IIS.  I need help rewriting only port 80. right now it's redirecting all non https requests to https.

Comment: FRT should also show you the various characteristics of the incoming requests to help you write better rules, so I wonder why you said that does not help.

Answer (score 4):

I found simple mistake in your rule condition is `<add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="XXXX" negate="true" />` **negate="true"**  means it does not match pattern and it rediect to the https. to impemnet your requiremnet you could use bwlow rule:

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
       <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
       <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="80" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

Comment: How do I achieve that using the URL rewrite module in IIS? In the module I chose "Matches the Pattern": ^80$ but it still redirects everything not just port 80.

Comment: this is how the rule looks like un module [image1](https://i.imgur.com/H2TF2pv.png) and this is failed request tracing result [image2](https://i.imgur.com/UchNs80.png) , [image3](https://i.imgur.com/BCV6Nos.png) , site bindings [image4](https://i.imgur.com/WLH5i1X.png). you could try to clear the browser history and cache and browse the siet again.

Comment: Jalpa, I mirrored what you had in image 1 and at first it was not working. At least not in Firefox. I then tried it in Chrome and it worked properly. I then reloaded the site in Firefox with add-ons disabled and it worked. Now I need to reset Firefox and it should be working.

Comment: I did a reset in Firefox and all is good. It might have actually been setup correctly, but FF was redirecting anyways. who knows.

Comment: What's the difference between redirecting to: https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}  and https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}? I used the latter before and had an issue where ?id=7 rewrote the value of id so it equaled 7,7. This caused a few web applications to fail until I directly linked directly to https.The strange thing is that the address bar does not show 7,7.

Comment: `negate="true"` in the `web.config` translates to the option **"Check if input string: Does Not Match the Pattern"** on the URL Rewrite tool GUI where you edit the Condition. Removing it changes the option to **"Check if input string: Matches the Pattern"**

Comment: Note that the `pattern="80"` should rather be `pattern="^80$"` to ensure it does not match a port like 8080.